# How to see which number within a value in a dictionary is bigger?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a program which will show all the teams that have more wins than losses. 
This is what I have tried so far but I get an error:

**File "C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/sfgthg.py", line 9, in 
    g=[c[0] for c in d.items() if c[1]>c[0]]**

**TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'**

```
d={}
while True:
    x=input("name of the team?(type stop if you want to stop")
    if x=="stop":
        break
    y=int(input("how many losses?"))
    z=int(input("how many wins?"))
    d[x]=[y,z]
g=[c[0] for c in d.items() if c[1]>c[0]]
print(g)
```

Comment: eval is dangerous!

Comment: Why do you use `eval` on `input`? You should be using `int(input(...))`

Comment: Replace `g=[c[0] for c in d.items() if c[1]>c[0]]` with `g=[key for key,value in d.items() if value[1]>value[0]]`.

Comment: @Sunny Patel thank you for responding! i changed it now! we were taught in school to write with eval

Comment: For more information, refer [How to iterate over dictionary in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-python/)

Comment: @AjayDabas thank you SO much!! it works :)

Comment: [`eval` is very dangerous first and foremost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). You don't want someone typing in `os.getcwd()` to get the working directory of your code, or (a lot worse](http://vipulchaskar.blogspot.com/2012/10/exploiting-eval-function-in-python.html)!

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate through the dictionary `d`, you should be using `d.values()`, because `d.items()` returns key-value pairs.

```
g=[c[0] for c in d.values() if c[1]>c[0]]
```

Or even better, you can capture like this:

```
g = filter(lambda c: c[1] > c[0], d)
```

and `g` will be a dictionary of winners.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, using eval can be dangerous. Also, you can use `dict.values()` to directly access the values, but I am assuming you want to create a new dictionary, so I will use `dict.items()` so that you can get the whole dict entry.

Anyways, this should work for the actual question you are asking:

```
g = [c for c in d.items() if c[1][0] > c[1][1]]
```

`c[0]` gives the key of the item, `c[1]` gives the value, therefore `c[1][0]` gives the number of wins, and `c[1][1]` gives the number of losses (assuming your array is structured as `[wins, losses]`.

edit: if you want only team names, change `[c for c.....]`to`[c[0] for c ......]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dict.items you can catch the key in a separate variable.
This will give you a list of the respective team names:

```
d={'Madrid':[2,1],
   'Barca':[1,2]}
g=[key for key,c in d.items() if c[1]>c[0]]
print(g)
```